# Is there any way to drag item between two fulscreen windows on mac?

Tags: macos, mac, usability

For example, chrome tabs. If you use cmd+`, windows are switched but tab is dropped. Do you know any usable way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way. You can drag to a non-fullscreen window but not fullscreen. [One of many, many reasons I never use fullscreen. It's just badly broken & always has been.]

Your use of  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>   is confusing - that doesn't switch between tabs, it switches between open windows …but also doesn't work in fullscreen [see above, broken.]  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>[</kbd>  or  <kbd>]</kbd>   will switch between tabs.